# Is it possible to know whenever an item in a tree has been renamed?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm using a QTreeWidget. I allowed the user to rename items in the tree. Yet,  whenever an item is renamed I have to manage something in the background. So I need to figure out when the user renames an item. I've seen the slot "ItemChanged" but I don't know if this slot is used only when an item is renamed.

here is how I set the item as renamable.

```cpp
default_item->setSelected(true);
default_item->setFlags(default_item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```

Comment: Assuming it uses TVN_ITEMCHANGED (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tvn-itemchanged), then it should be used for all properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `itemChanged` signal is emitted whenever data changes for any of the roles in the item. That includes when the `Qt::DisplayRole` changes because the user edited the name, or when you call `QTreeWidgetItem::setData`. It's also emitted in some other cases like when flags change and when the item is enabled/disabled.

If you want to know only when the name changes, then you can connect directly to the `dataChanged` signal of the underlying model and inspect the `roles` argument for the `Qt::DisplayRole` role. For example:

```
connect(treeWidget->model(), &QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged,
[](const QModelIndex &index, const QModelIndex &, const QVector<int> &roles) {
  if (roles.contains(Qt::DisplayRole))
    qDebug("Display role changed!");
});
```